# How to automatically compile less files in an asp.net core project

Tags: .net-core, less

I have an asp.net core project.

This project contains less style sheet files.

I can see a compilerconfig.json and compilerconfig.json.defaults files at the root of the project.

This 2 files contains less compilation rules.

But when I type "dotnet build", the less files are not compiled in css.

Is there a specific command to type in addition of "dotnet build" ?

Thanks

Comment: you mean "dotnet publish" ? I have already tried: It does not work too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can right click compilerconfig.json and enable it. Also it has Ci support.

Nuget Package: [source](https://www.nuget.org/packages/BuildWebCompiler2022/1.14.8)

```
<PackageReference Include="BuildWebCompiler2022" Version="1.14.8" />
```

[image]

**cmd**:
[image]

Comment: Thanks but this is a visual studio feature. I want to compile this file in my build pipeline… (command line)

Comment: I have edited answer, you can do it with `BuildWebCompiler2022` package.

Comment: This is a visual studio extension. So it will only compile if i am building With visual studio…

Comment: I have built in cmd without use visual studio, I posted the results visually. Also BuildWebCompiler2022 is not extension, is nuget package